# Как добавить больше 4-х значений в функцию create_user()?

Tags: python, django

Хочу добавить больше 4-х параметров при регистрации. Выдает ошибку: create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 6 were given

Вьюха

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import TemplateView




class RegisterView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "access/reg.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            surname = request.POST.get('surname')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
            date = request.POST.get('date')


            if password == password2:
                User.objects.create_user(name, surname, email, password, date)
                return redirect(reverse("login"))

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

шаблон

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Регистрация</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #EDEEF0;">

    <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 50px; background-color: #E25C5B;">
      <div class="container"><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: #EDEEF0;"><h4>DjiSoc <span class="badge" style="background-color: #DD595C; color: #EDEEF0;">2020</span></h4></button></div>

       <div class="container" style="height: 800px; padding-top: 100px;">

        <div class="head" style="width: 90%; height: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); padding: 50px; margin: auto;">

            <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: #E25C5B;"><a href="/" style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;">На главную</a></button>

            <h1 style="color: #E25C5B; text-align: center;">Регистрация</h1>

            <form style="margin-top: 75px;" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputName4">Имя</label>
                  <input type="text" name='name'class="form-control" id="inputName4">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputSurname4">Фамилия</label>
                  <input type="text" name='surname'class="form-control" id="inputSurname4">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inpuEmail1">Электронная почта</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inpuEmail1" placeholder="name@example.com">
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputPass">Пароль</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPass">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputPass1">Подтвердите пароль</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" id="inputPass1">
              </div>
              <form>
                   
                    <p>
                        <label for="localdate">Дата рождения: </label>
                        <input type="date" name="date" id="localdate" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 45px; border-radius: 4px;" name="date"/>
                    </p>
                   
                </form>
              
              <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: #E25C5B; color: #FFFFFF; margin-left: 300px; margin-top: 100px;">Готово</button>
            </form>

        </div>  

       </div>   






       <footer class="container" style="height: 100px;">
        
       </footer>












<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

create_user ожидает только имя пользователя в качестве позиционного параметра. Все остальные данные должны быть переданы в качестве аргументов ключевых слов.

```
User.objects.create_user(
self.cleaned_data['name'],
surname=self.cleaned_data['surname'],
email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
password=self.cleaned_data['password']
date=self.cleaned_data['date']
)
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385119/create-user-takes-from-2-to-4-positional-arguments-but-6-were-given

Comment: а вместо чего и куда это вставить?

Comment: @SiRex2307 После проверки password == password2 замените!

Comment: cleaned_data не найдена